# console output is different in eclipse than it is in terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I have a simple program, its supposed to print to the console, a public static variable. In the program, this variable is incremented, and then ultimately printed. Now here is the thing, in eclipse, the output shows that the variable has been incremented, but when I copy this same program to a folder on my desktop (package names within class files are adjusted of course) the program runs fine, but the this static variable, when printed, is 0. When run in eclipse, this program prints out the correct output, a long, lets say 500.

Can anyone think of a reason this might be, assuming that all else is correct, does anyone know of any restrictions that output to a console might have?

Comment: Do you copy the compiled class files or the java sources?

Comment: Originally I had copied the java sources into another folder, but I tried copy and pasting the whole package out of eclipse and onto my desktop, running it, and it acts correctly now. This topic should be deleted lol

Comment: Show the code at least. From your description it seems to be short enough.

Comment: Where is your code ? :)

Comment: its a short but fairly complex  simulation of a computer networks synchronization algorithm,  I'l show the code though, ina few min